# Is there a way to spoof Mac-Address for selected programs only

Tags: c#, winforms, hardware, mac-address

Sorry for the noob question, but I want certain programs on my PC to think that my Mac address is `xx_xx_xx_xx_xx`. Is that even possible or I am thinking about the wrong things.

Explanation if you'd like to read what I want to do.

There's a program on my PC that we bought from a vendor a long time ago. It requires a security file which was made with the the Mac address of the PC. Now that the vendor has moved away from providing software services I am stuck with an old machine. I want to be able to run the software on a newer machine. It's possible since we got our other machine upgraded to windows 10 a few years back.

Now what I want to do is that I want this program on my PC only to think that the Mac address is one from my old PC. Is that possible.?

Comment: I don't have a real answer for you but in the worst case, is moving the NIC to your newer PC an option? Are you sure that the software is tied to the MAC address alone and not other factors or something else entirely?

Comment: Absolutely sure it's the Mac address only. Moving the NIC is no longer an option since the card died.

Comment: Many NICs have drivers allowing you to change the MAC address of the NIC. If yours doesn't, search the web for a network adapter that allows changing its MAC address through its driver. Or just run the thing in a VM that is configured appropriately with a virtual NIC using the MAC address you need...

Comment: I get that but my query is only for "that" program to think Mac address is what I set it too. I don't want it to be the old Mac address on my network.

Comment: Then run that program, and only that program in a VM...

Comment: I DID not think of that. That's genius.

Comment: Also not sure how your question is related to C# or Winforms or programming in general. superuser.com would be the better place to ask about these things...

Comment: Since originally I was thinking about doing it for a selected program only. That program is made with C# and winforms